# slideToggle and :visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.3.2

When using the `sliderToggle` method, the `:visible` expression never seems to return anything other than true.

If I manually use `show`/ `hide` in conjunction with `:visible` expression it'll work just fine.

Example of **failure**:

```
jQuery(".fileNode .nodeExpander").click(function() {
    var notes = jQuery(this).parent().siblings(".fileNotes");
    notes.slideToggle ("fast");

    var isVisible = notes.is(":visible"); // Always returns true...

    // Do stuff based on visibility...
});
```

Example of **working**:

```
jQuery(".fileNode .nodeExpander").click(function() {
    var notes = jQuery(this).parent().siblings(".fileNotes");
    var isVisible = notes.is(":visible");

    if (isVisible)
        notes.hide("fast");
    else
        notes.show("fast");

    // Do stuff based on visibility...
});
```

Some html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="fileNode">
        <img src="<%= Url.Content ("~/Images/Collapse.png") %>" alt="<%= UIResources.CollpaseAltText %>" class="nodeExpander" />
    </li>
    <li class="fileLink">
        <%= Html.ActionLink (file.Name, "Details", new { id = file.FileId }) %>
    </li>
    <li class="fileNotes">
        <%= file.Description %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm assuming that the `slideToggle` doesn't do a `show`/ `hide` - is there something else I can check?

I've tried in Firefox 3.5, IE 7, 8 and Chrome 4...all with the same results.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your first (non-working) code fragment will be testing `:visible` while slideToggle is mid-transition (more precisely, it tests it just after the transition starts.)  Regardless of whether you're opening or closing, the mid-transition state will be `:visible` - so you always get `true`.

Try checking `.is(":visible")` before calling `slideToggle`

Comment: Of course! Thanks, feel like a muppet now - by calling  var isVisible = !notes.is(":visible"); before the slideToggle I get the answer required. Thank you!

Comment: It is a bit counter-intuitive, but makes perfect sense. If only we have an internal slide-up-status for the jQuery object...

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a handler.

```
notes.slideToggle ("fast", function() { 
  var isVisible = notes.is(":visible");
});
```