# Issue with is visible toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $('.sub-menu').on('click', function(){
    var menu = $(this).parents('.row').next()
    $(menu).slideToggle();
    var text = $(menu).is(':visible') ? 'open' : 'close';
    $('.sub-menu-status').text(text);
  });
```

For some reason it only outputs `close` it never writes `open`.

Inspected code and tried this variation but get the same result as above:

```
  var text = $(menu).css('display') == 'none' ? 'open' : 'close';
```

Can someone help me understand this? Thanks.

jsFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=LlkSSawSsb

Comment: add a fiddle for your problem.

Comment: for some reason it jsFiddle is only allowing me to create a share session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345652/slidetoggle-and-visible) question I get that `is(':visible')` will be checking when the `slideToggle` transition starts. So it always returns `true`.

Try this

```
$('.sub-menu').on('click', function(){
    var menu = $(this).parents('.row').next()
    var text = $(menu).is(':visible') ? 'close' : 'open';
    $(menu).slideToggle();   
    $('.sub-menu-status').text(text);
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/12/)

Or DO it in callback of `slideToggle`

```
 $('.sub-menu').on('click', function(){
    var menu = $(this).parents('.row').next()
    $(menu).slideToggle(function() {
        var text = $(menu).is(':visible') ? 'open' : 'close';
        $('.sub-menu-status').text(text);
    })
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/13/)