# Getting Visiblity status of a div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get status of a div visibility , its display is block or none here is my code

```
 $('#btn').live('click', function (event) {

      var status = $('#menuDiv').is(":visible");
         alert(status);

 });
```

but it always return false even div is visible
Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/50at8ydj/4/

Comment: you have a typo in your fiddle = id-menuDiv instead of id=menuDiv (same for the other id) - just change that and it'll work

Comment: Set proper ids in your fiddle.

Comment: well that's embracing .. sorry guys  ...

Comment: @matthias_h can u plz look at the updated fiddle after putting toggle i am getting true  even if div is hidden

Comment: @AdilWaqar sure; btw the id-"contentDiv" should be id="contentDiv", and for the result of :visible in combination with toggle just have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345652/slidetoggle-and-visible

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ( $('#menuDiv').css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
  { 
     ...
  }
  else { ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just checking:
`$('#menuDiv').css("display") === 'none'` (or `==='block'`, depends on your need/common case)

so simple....

Answer (score 0):

Hoping to help You consider to change Your function to:

```
jQuery('#btn').click(function (event) {
            var status = $('#menuDiv').is(":visible");
            $('#menuDiv').toggle(!status);
            alert(status);
});
```

In practice, the toggle must accept a boolean value "showOrHide"  indicating whether to show or hide the elements. For more info see http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide

bye

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just have a typo..

In HTML you wrote `id-` instead of `id=`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50at8ydj/6/)